# npm install -g dredd seems to instal but dredd not working

Tags: macos, npm-install, dredd

I've installed dredd globally on mac os but when calling dredd it comes back command not found

```
➜  test git:(master) dredd
zsh: command not found: dredd
```

Not sure if this is being saved in the correct place or there's an extra step i'm missing.

My initial install was:

```
➜  test git:(master) npm install -g dredd
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.6: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
/Users/bob/.npm-packages/bin/dredd -> /Users/bob/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/dredd/bin/dredd
+ dredd@4.8.2
updated 1 package in 5.563s
```

Comment: Does executing `/Users/bob/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/dredd/bin/dredd` work? Maybe for some reason you don't have the `/Users/bob/.npm-packages/bin/` directory in your system path.

Comment: Hi @HonzaJavorek this seems to get a little closer but then asks me to install **pip install dredd_hooks** which I do, but it returns 'Requirement already satisfied'

Comment: What does `which dredd` and `dredd --version` output? And `which dredd_hooks`?

Answer (score 0):

try to run using

```
./node_modules/.bin/dredd
```

and make sure `dredd.yml` exists as in `./dredd.yml`